# Rails 3 - Is there a helper that given a date will return "Today", "Yesterday", or "x days ago"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, helper

Basically, I want the equivalent of "time_ago_in_words", but with a granularity of days, not more than that. (And for "Dates", not "DateTimes")

Does something like this exist?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this helper for yourself pretty straightforwardly.

The calculation for # of days using Dates is simply `delta = (to_date - from_date).to_i`.

```
today = Date.today
past_date = Date.new(2012, 9, 28)
puts (today - past_date).to_i
```

So here's a complete sample, including the actual message construction:

```
def days_ago_in_words(from_date, to_date, options={})
  delta = (to_date - from_date).to_i
  I18n.with_options :locale => options[:locale], :scope => :'datetime.distance_in_words' do |locale|
    locale.t :x_days, :count => delta
  end
end
```